# Jellybean (API 16) does not still show up on my Android SDK Manager

Tags: android

Is it just me or is anyone else not seeing the latest Android (Jellybean) showing up on their SDK manager? I've looked [everywhere](http://www.teamandroid.com/2012/06/27/install-android-41-try-jelly-bean-sdk-now/) and it seems wherever I look, people are seeing it showing up on their SDK manager just fine.

I have updated by SDK tools to rev 20 and ran all other ADT updates.

I'm not in the US - and I'm wondering if this is still not available for non-US developers? I yet to come across anything that mentions this.

Comment: Shows up fine for me in Canada.

Comment: its showing fine for me. can you post the screen shot of your sdk manager.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try one of these:

- Android SDK Manager > Tools (menu bar) > Settings > Manifest cache > Clear Cache (and maybe uncheck "Use download cache")
- If that doesn't work, try running SDK Manager directly (i.e. not from within Eclipse). If running from Windows make sure you Run as Administrator.

Comment: Oh man, that did the trick. I opened up the SDK manager from OUT of Eclipse, Tools -> Options and clicked clear cache (the menu item does not show up if you opened it within Eclipse). It shows up now. Nice catch!

Comment: Cool it worked for me too. For those wondering, on Linux the SDK manager can be launched with the command : android-sdks/tools/android

Comment: On OSX, it's Preferences... > Manifest Cache > Clear Cache.

Answer (score 8):

For my case, I could only see Android 4.0.3 (API 15) whenever I open the SDK Manager outside Eclipse, "Reload" from the toolbar, or click "Options". Just now, I installed the 2 things that it recommended for Tools, and then suddently everything shows up!

Comment: what were those 2 things ?

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem, and was able to see the new repo after selecting:

Packages > Reload (from the SDK Manager toolbar)

Answer (score 1):

I solve that by open AVD Manager from command promt...

Command(Window[Linux too]) : .../android-sdks/tools/android

Answer (score 0):

In my case on MAC OSX problem was with version of my ADT, I downloaded the Latest Version of ADT from [Android Installing Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) and Installed using Eclipse (Menu) Help--> Install New Software-->Add and selected the ADT zip file  and when installation completed i restarted my Eclipse and then i choose (Menu) Window-->Android SDK Manager--> Packages-->Reload

This time It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by updating my SDK tools. I downloaded latest "Android SDK Tools" and "Android SDK Platform-tools".